# SAPUI5 Strange data binding behaviour

Tags: sapui5

It's pretty silly problem but I have no idea why is it happening. I heve this in my controller:

```
this.getView().setModel(this.placesModel, "myCity");
```

then I set the data with Ajax request to my express RESTFull app and in View.xml

```
  <List items="{path: 'myCity>/people'}">
      <CustomListItem>                           
          <VBox>
            <Title text="Person:"/>
            <Label text="{myCity>/people/name}"/>
            <Label text="{myCity>/people/age}"/>
          </VBox>            
        </CustomListItem>
   </List>
```

I have object `myCity` with few properties. One of them is object `people` which is array of objects. When I try to list them like that I can see that all my people get listed but without corresponding name and age. Also I find it hard to understend when to use `>` when `/` when when `>/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic binding syntax with model name is `{(model_name)>(path_to_property)}`, if you don't have a model name (default model) you need to specify only `{path_to_property}`.

The initial slash (/) is needed if you don't have a `contextbinding`. In your case you have `contextbinding` set on List, so you don't need to use the slash.

Updated code:

```
  <List items="{path: 'myCity>/people'}">
      <CustomListItem>                           
          <VBox>
            <Title text="Person:"/>
            <Label text="{myCity>name}"/>
            <Label text="{myCity>age}"/>
          </VBox>            
        </CustomListItem>
   </List>
```

For more information refer to [Binding Path](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9.html).

Comment: Just adding one thing to avoid misunderstandings. Using slash at the begining of your binding path means it is an `absolute` path. So it points from the root of your model to the inner property. If you don't use the slash at the beginning, it is a `relative` path, so this path will be prefixed with the path of the binded context. So in your list, all the bindings in your CustomListItem template should be relatively binded to the context path you specify in the `items` aggregation.